# how to connect mongodb with nodejs using blocked code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I want to write a blocked code to fetch data from mongodb using node.js.
Please provide me a sample function which fetch data from mongodb in node.js using callback or using blocked code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
this.db = new Db('node-mongo-blog', new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
  this.db.open(function(err){
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Within the open function you can do your database related stuff.